# how does LaunchScreen.storyboard redirect to Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm newbie of iOS developer, and I know that is very simple question but I really can't understand reason.

when I build `SingleViewApplication`, Xcode auto generate `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and `Main.storyboard`,

but I can't find any code like `[self.navigationController pushViewController:]` which may choose that what view controller enter stack as last one of top-level view,

I only find `ViewController.{h,m}` as first and see no logic that change view from `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to `Main.storyboard`.

could anyone help? thanks..

Answer (score 2):

**Main.storyboard** file and **LaunchScreen** is define in your project property.
you can find it by click on project in xcode and then in below target you can find this two name you can choose your own by selecting dropdown given beside label.

and other redirecting to **LaunchScreen** to **Main.storyboard** you can refer *info.plist* file in your project and also *AppDelegate.h* and *AppDelegate.m*

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the iOS first looks for LaunchScreen.storyboard file and shows it for some time and when it is done with it, it looks for Main.storyboard.

These names are hardwired in the plist as mentioned by Tejas in his answer and you can change these.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` is pushing the `Main.storyboard`. Everything is managed behind the scenes and you can't change this behavior.

What you can change is the initial `View Controller` in your `Main.storyboard` so that it is instantiated immediately after the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` disappears and the app is fully loaded.

Comment: What is the change to get Main.storyboard instantiated after LaunchScreen.storyboard?